# Magento Category Pages are too slow

Tags: category, magento-1.6, profiler, ce-1.6.1.0

Time to first byte is almost 6 seconds and full page load time is 8.60 second

I try to run profiler and here is the results

Memory usage: real: 45350912, emalloc: 44510384[image]

I can't figure out why page is too slow.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Magento
     *
     * NOTICE OF LICENSE
     *
     * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
     * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
     * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
     * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
     * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
     * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
     *
     * DISCLAIMER
     *
     * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
     * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
     * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
     *
     * @category    design
     * @package     base_default
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
     * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     * Modified by 2jdesign.co.uk(Developer 6) Date:12/28/2011
     */
    ?>
    <?php
    /**
     * Product list template
     *
     * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
     */
    ?>
    <?php
        $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    ?>
    <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-products">
     <h2 class="product-title">
         <?php
          /*BOF 2jdesign.co.uk (Dev 1)*/
          // For Category name on products list page //
          $current_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
          if($current_page=='catalog'){
          $currCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
            echo  $currCat->getName();
         }
         /*EOF*/
        ?>
        </h2>
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>   
        <?php // List mode ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 3; ?>
        <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
        <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
        <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
              <div class="list-top">
               <div class="list-bottom">
                <?php // Product Image ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php echo Mage::helper('productlabel')->showLabel($_product,'category',$_productCollection);?><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(307,228); ?>" width="307" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <?php // Product description ?>
                <div class="product-shop">
                    <div class="f-fix">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php //echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="list-price-left">
                        <div style="min-height:48px;float:left;">
                         <div class="price-per-me">
                         <?php //$price_per_meter_sq=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('price_per_meter_sq')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);             
                         // if($price_per_meter_sq){    
                             // echo "testprice".$price_per_meter_sq;
                            // print_r($_product);
                           ?>                         
                          <?php $currency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
                          <?php
                            $_packm = $_product->getPackm2();
                            $_price = $_product->getPrice();
                            $_tax = $_product->getTaxPercent();                     
                            if(isset($_packm) && ($_packm!='')){                            
                                //$packmarray = explode('.',$_packm);
                                $packmarray = $_packm; // pack meter for calulation to per meter sq
                                //print_r($packmarray);
                                $pricewithtax = $_price*$_tax/100; // tax calculation
                                $includetaxprice = $_price+$pricewithtax; // price with include tax             
                                $packmPrice =  $includetaxprice/$packmarray; // final formula for per meter sq price                    
                                echo $currency.$price_per_meter_sq = number_format($packmPrice, 2, '.', ''); ?><label>per m<sup>2</sup>(<?php echo $_packm; ?>)</label>  
                           <?php } ?>

                         </div>
                         <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                         </div>
                         <?php                  
                          $manufacturer=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);             $imageurl=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/brand/';
                          $manufacturer=str_replace(' ', '',$manufacturer);                 
                          $brands_image=$imageurl.$manufacturer.'.png';?>   
                          <span style="float:right;padding-top:6px;">
                          <img src="<?php echo $brands_image; ?>" width="73" height="34" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>" />
                          </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="list-price-desc">
                        <div class="desc std">
                            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="att-left">
                         <?php                  
                        $delivery_included=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('delivery_included')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
                        $imageurl=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/brand/';
                            if($delivery_included=='Yes'){
                            $delivery_img = $imageurl.'delivery_inc.png';?>                                 
                             <span style="float:left;padding-right:11px;">
                             <img src="<?php echo $delivery_img; ?>" alt="Delivery Included"/>
                 </span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <span style="float:left;">
                         <?php $available_to_buy_individually=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_to_buy_individually')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);                  
                       if($available_to_buy_individually){      
                       $baseurl=$available_to_buy_individually; ?>  
                      <?php $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();                     
                       if ($baseurl!=$url) {
                       $fullpackurlindividual = $this->getUrl($available_to_buy_individually);
                         $fullpackurlindividual = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($fullpackurlindividual);
                        $last_character_individual      = substr($fullpackurlindividual, -1 );
                           if($last_character_individual=='/'){
                               $fullpackurlindividual = substr($fullpackurlindividual, 0, -1);
                           }
                       ?>
                         <span class="availableindiually"><a href="<?php echo $fullpackurlindividual; ?>">&nbsp;</a></span>             
                        <?php }}else{ ?>
                        <?php $available_to_buy_by_per_m2=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_to_buy_by_per_m2')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);                 
                          if($available_to_buy_by_per_m2){      
                          $baseurl=$available_to_buy_by_per_m2; ?>  
                            <?php $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();                     
                              if ($baseurl!=$url) {
                              $fullpackurlm2 = $this->getUrl($available_to_buy_by_per_m2);
                              $fullpackurlm2 = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($fullpackurlm2);
                              $last_character_m2      = substr($fullpackurlm2, -1 );
                                  if($last_character_m2=='/'){
                                      $fullpackurlm2 = substr($fullpackurlm2, 0, -1);
                                  }
                              ?>
                            <span class="product-list-availablemeter"><a href="<?php echo $fullpackurlm2; ?>">&nbsp;</a></span> 
                        <?php }}}?> 
                       </span>  
                       <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="list-add-cart"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php //echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

        <?php else: ?>

        <?php // Grid Mode ?>

        <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php 
            $_columnCount = 3; 
            $imageurl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/brand/';
        ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <ul class="products-grid">
            <?php endif ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="middle-contain">
                   <h2 class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                           <?php 
                                $productname = explode('-',$_product->getName());
                                $firstskip = 0;
                                $dash_length = count($productname);
                                foreach($productname as $name)
                                {
                                    if($firstskip == 0)
                                    {
                                        echo $name."<br/>";
                                    }
                                    else if($firstskip == $dash_length)
                                    {
                                        echo "-".$name;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "-".$name."<br/>";
                                    }
                                    $firstskip++;
                                }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>



                    <?php /* ?><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><?php echo Mage::helper('productlabel')->showLabel($_product,'category',$_productCollection);?><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(201,151); ?>" width="201" height="151" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <?php */ ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>

                    <div class="price-des">
                        <div class="price-left">
                            <div style="min-height:73px;float:left;width:112px;">
                                <div class="price-per-me">            
                                    <?php $currency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
                                    <?php
                                        $_packm = $_product->getPackm2();
                                        $_price = $_product->getPrice();
                                        $_tax = $_product->getTaxPercent();                     

                                        if(isset($_packm) && ($_packm!=''))
                                        {                           
                                            $packmarray = $_packm;
                                            $pricewithtax = $_price*$_tax/100;
                                            $includetaxprice = $_price+$pricewithtax;               
                                            $packmPrice =  $includetaxprice/$packmarray;

                                            echo $currency.$price_per_meter_sq = number_format($packmPrice, 2, '.', ''); ?><label>per m<sup>2</sup><br />(<?php echo $_packm."m<sup>2</sup> pack"; ?>)</label>  
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>              
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                <?php
                                    $_units_per_pack = $_product->getUnits_per_pack();
                                    if(($_packm=='') && ($_units_per_pack!=''))
                                    {
                                        echo "<br /><br /><label>(".$_units_per_pack." units)</label><br />";   
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </div>

                    <?php                   
                        $manufacturer = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);             
                        //$imageurl=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/brand/';
                        $manufacturer = str_replace(' ', '',$manufacturer); 
                        $brands_image = $imageurl.$manufacturer.'.png';
                    ?>  
                    <span style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $brands_image; ?>" width="73" height="34" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>" />
                    </span>
                </div>

                    <div class="att-right">
                     <?php                  
                        $delivery_included = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('delivery_included')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                        if($delivery_included=='Yes')
                        {
                            $delivery_img = $imageurl.'delivery_inc.png';
                    ?>                                  
                            <span style="float:right;padding:0 0px 7px 0;">
                                <img src="<?php echo $delivery_img; ?>" alt="Delivery Included"/>
                            </span>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <span style="float:right;margin-right:-4px;">
                    <?php 
                        $available_to_buy_individually=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_to_buy_individually')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                        if($available_to_buy_individually)
                        {       
                            $baseurl=$available_to_buy_individually; 
                    ?>  
                    <?php 
                            $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();                     

                            if ($baseurl != $url) 
                            {
                                $fullpackurlindividual = $this->getUrl($available_to_buy_individually);
                                $fullpackurlindividual = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($fullpackurlindividual);
                                $last_character_individual      = substr($fullpackurlindividual, -1 );
                                if($last_character_individual=='/')
                                {
                                    $fullpackurlindividual = substr($fullpackurlindividual, 0, -1);
                                }
                    ?>
                                <span class="availableindiually">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $fullpackurlindividual; ?>">&nbsp;</a>
                                </span>             
                    <?php 
                            }
                        }
                        else{ 
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                            $available_to_buy_by_per_m2 = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_to_buy_by_per_m2')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                            if($available_to_buy_by_per_m2)
                            {       
                                $baseurl=$available_to_buy_by_per_m2; 
                    ?>  
                    <?php 
                                $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();                     
                                if ($baseurl!=$url) 
                                {
                                    $fullpackurlm2 = $this->getUrl($available_to_buy_by_per_m2);
                                    $fullpackurlm2 = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($fullpackurlm2);
                                    $last_character_m2 = substr($fullpackurlm2, -1 );
                                    if($last_character_m2 == '/')
                                    {
                                      $fullpackurlm2 = substr($fullpackurlm2, 0, -1);
                                    }
                    ?>
                                    <span class="availablemeter"><a href="<?php echo $fullpackurlm2; ?>">&nbsp;</a></span>  
                    <?php 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>  
                    </span> 
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div class="short"><?php echo $_product->getShortDescription(); ?></div>

                    <?php //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('ekomimeetsmage/frontend_product_name')->setData('product', $_product)->setTemplate('ekomimeetsmage/product/name.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php //echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                       <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="toolbar-bottom">
            <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please share code of list.phtm;

Comment: List.phtml added to question

Comment: Please check 2column-right.phtml

Comment: what do you mean by check 2column-right.phtml my current page layout is 2column-right.phtml

Comment: based on your profile output your TTFB is 3.5 not 6

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=4fe9b7e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to me it looks like your shop layout is too heavy for your hardware and software, upgrade to php7 and fine tune mysql with mysqltuner, get more CPU and RAM**

**quick fix to hide your performance issues** - install Full Page Cache extension

**more tedious path:**

here are a few things to look for:

1. *aitsys_rewriter* observer takes 0.6s on every page request! consider disabling aitsys extensions.
2. *get_tablename* and *init:stores* take too long - do you have mysql query cache enabled?
3. closely inspect these templates:

   1. frontend/default/default/template/magiczoomplus/list.phtml - 0.5s
   2. frontend/default/lsd/template/catalog/category/view.phtml - 0.6s
   3. frontend/default/default/template/mgxtips/catalog/layout/filter.phtml - 1.2s (looks like custom module, try to disable it and see if TTFB drops)
   4. I see you load catalog/product/price.phtml 30 times - try to lower that number

Taken from [Magento TTFB optimization](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-ttfb-optimization) .

Also see 34 steps to [improve magento performance](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento).

Disclaimer: I wrote the above articles.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: In my web site Profiler : mage  took 5.2428 . Do you have any idea why it took that much

Comment: mage time is a sum of all call times below it. what is below it? attach screenshot

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_JiSIiJ5Z3pLHAYsRC281pOa2NyW-bLTjxEJZ1rDAnU/edit?usp=sharing   Sheet3

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2010528/c897be23cb065e54de278cf4a2f1e856

Comment: i suggest you attach count and memory columns as well and submit it as another question